# If $C_G(x)=G$, where $G$ is non-abelian, then $x=1$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $C_G(x)=\{g\in G: gx=xg\}$ denote the Centralizer of $x$. Assume $G$ is **non-abelian**.

If $C_G(x)=G$, is it true that $x=1$?

---

I have a feeling it is true, but I am having a bit of a mental block here. Clearly, the converse is true $C_G(1)=G$ since everything commutes with 1.

Suppose $G$ is non-abelian, then there exists $a,b\in G$ such that $ab\neq ba$.

I tried playing around with $$abx=axb=xab$$

etc to get a contradiction but I can't seem to do it (move the $b$ to the left of $a$).

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Consider scalar matrix in the group of 2-by-2 invertible matrix.

Comment: No: $C_G(x)=G$ if and only if $x$ is an element of the *center* of $G$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the group $G=G_1 \times G_2$ where $G_1$ is abelian and $G_2$ is not.

What is $C_G(g,e)$?

Comment: Ah.. The whole group. Nice.